# Is there a way to use VBA for Excel to output a formula to a specific cell in an Excel worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new at programming. I feel like this should be a simple fix but I cannot find anything that works. I am trying to use a `Select Case` structure to write a different formula to a cell depending on the selected case. If I type:

```
Sheet1.Range("g10").Value = "=IF(SUM(F10)>0,SUM((F10-15)),"")"
```

I get an error:

> Run-time error '1004'
>   Application-defined or object-defined error.

I can get it to work if I include spaces like so:

```
Sheet1.Range("g10").Value = " =IF(SUM(F10)>0,SUM((F10-15)),"") "
```

but then Excel puts it into the cell like text, not as a formula (it doesn't **do** anything).

I have tried a few different methods but have run into the same issue. Is it possible to do this?

I apologize if this has been asked and answered, but I wasn't able to find anyone referencing this specific problem.

Comment: (a) If you are writing a formula, use the `Formula` property.  (The `Value` property will **sometimes** work, but be safe and use the right property.) (b) Double-quotation mark characters within a string literal need to be escaped - so you need `Sheet1.Range("g10").Formula = "=IF(SUM(F10)>0,SUM((F10-15)),"""")"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel (2007) VBA - .Formula with quotes in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142448/excel-2007-vba-formula-with-quotes-in-it).  Also duplicate of [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9024724/6535336), and [How to create strings containing double quotes in Excel formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216616/6535336) and lots more.

Comment: Thank you, I did not find those results in my previous searches. I will strive to be more diligent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sum a single cell ie `SUM(F10)` Also `SUM((F10-15))` is the same as `F10-15`.

Try this: `Sheet1.Range("g10").Formula = "=IF(F10>0,F10-15,"""")"` Also note, you needed to double the double quotes towards the end.

Note, you can do this on a range too like this:

`Sheet1.Range("g10:g20").Formula = "=IF(F10>0,F10-15,"""")"` and it is smart enough to increment the references for you for the 10 cells.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong property. You need .formula not .value

```
worksheets("sheet1").range("g10").formula = "=IF(SUM(F10)>0,SUM((F10-15)),"")"
```

Comment: You still need to fix the double-quotation marks - at the moment the code will generate a formula of `=IF(SUM(F10)>0,SUM((F10-15)),")` which isn't a valid Excel formula.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to type out the formula and then turn on the Macro Recorder and double-click on the cell with the forums, then turn off the Macro recorder and examine your code.  That should give you what you want.